# How can spaces be ignored in the input, but printed at the end?

Tags: python

I need to count how many times the same character is repeated and then use that count as an offset in ASCII. For example: `** *` should give `B A`. Because 2 *s mean B (the second letter) and 1 * means A (the first letter).

My problem is that spaces are considered as a character and translated as `A`. How can I ignore spaces in the input, but include them in my print statement? I currently get `BAA` instead. This is my code:

```
def main():
    encrypted = "** *"
    #input("Enter an encrypted message: ")
    
    count = 0
    decoded = ''
    
    for i, ch in enumerate(encrypted):
        if i == 0 or ch == encrypted[i-1]:
            count += 1
        else:
            decoded += chr(count + 64)
            count = 1

    if count > 0:
        decoded += chr(count + 64)
            
    print(decoded)
    
main()
```

Another example: the input:

```
********bbbbb&&&&&&&&&&&&999999999999zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz ********bbbbb&&&&&&&&&&&&999999999999zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

should print out `HELLO HELLO`.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem with minimal changes, you can just add a special check for the space:

```py
...
    for i, ch in enumerate(encrypted):
        if encrypted[i-1] == ' ':
            decoded += ' '
        elif i == 0 or ch == encrypted[i - 1]:
...
```

But you can opt for a simpler way by using [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

def main():
    encrypted = "** *"
    # input("Enter an encrypted message: ")

    decoded = ""
    for key, group in groupby(encrypted):
        if key == ' ':
            decoded += ' '
        else:
            decoded += chr(sum(1 for _ in group) + 64)

    print(decoded)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

how about a little different approach? Every char is seperated by a space, so just `split` the input to a `list` and check the length of each char.
Like this:

```
def main():
    
    encrypted = "** *"
    #input("Enter an encrypted message: ")
    
    count = 0
    
    inp_list= encrypted.split(' ')
    decoded = [chr(len(elem) + 64) for elem in inp_list]
    
    for ch in decoded:
        print(ch, end=' ')

main()
```

Output:    `B A`

Comment: I tried this using a larger input "********bbbbb&&&&&&&&&&&&999999999999zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz ********bbbbb&&&&&&&&&&&&999999999999zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz" which should print HELLO HELLO, but it prints t t

Comment: I guessed it is only a simple example to show the problem here, but I thought I give it a try.... t t makes sense, because my code would split that string into two big blocks and just count the length

Comment: No worries; I appreciate your help!

Comment: @JonolOakwood For the future, this example should be in the question itself to give users more chances to test their code and help you get better answers...

Answer (score 0):

I like the approach by Tomerikoo, though this is a different approach using what you've already written.

Since your code works without spaces, just run it once per word and join the result together.

```
def decode_word(word):
    decoded = ''
    count = 0
    for i, ch in enumerate(word):
        if i == 0 or ch == word[i-1]:
            count += 1
        else:
            decoded += chr(count + 64)
            count = 1

    if count > 0:
        decoded += chr(count + 64)

    return decoded


def decode_string(encrypted):
    return ' '.join(map(decode_word, encrypted.split()))


print(decode_string("** *"))
# B A
print(decode_string("********bbbbb&&&&&&&&&&&&999999999999zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz ********bbbbb&&&&&&&&&&&&999999999999zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"))
# HELLO HELLO
```